# Angular Jasmine Service Testing broadcast not called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a fairly simple service that basically catches error, enhances them with a specific error type and error message and broadcast the error event so that parts of my application can deal with the problem. A simplified version can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/judotuluselu/1/edit?js,output).

The Service looks something like this:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .factory('errors', function ($rootScope) {
    function broadcast (error) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('err:'+error.type, error.message, error.error);
    }
    return {
      catch: function (type, message) {
        return function (error) {
          broadcast({
            type: type,
            message: message,
            error: error
          });
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Now I would like to test with Jasmine if this service does actually broadcast the error.

To do so I've written the following test.

```
describe("errors: Errors (unit testing)", function() {
  "use strict";

  var errors,
      rootScope;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('app');

    inject(function (_errors_, $injector) {
      errors = _errors_;
      rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      spyOn(rootScope, '$broadcast');
    });
  });

  it('should broadcast error event', inject(function ($q) {
    $q.reject('error')
      .catch(errors.catch('type', 'message'));

    expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Unfortunately the test is never passed because `rootScope.$broadcast` is never called.

I am not sure but I assume it has something to do with the fact that the broadcast is encapsulated in the private `broadcast` function. Does anybody have an idea how to get the test running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rejected the promise but you need to invoke the digest cycle before you can test so that the error callback of the promise is invoked.

Do:-

```
     $q.reject('error').catch(errors.catch('type', 'message'));

     rootScope.$digest();

     expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UoOiTH?p=preview)**

Comment: Oh wow thanks, that was actually an easy fix! I should have thought about that. :)